# OrientDB: list all indexes

Tags: orientdb

For the life of me I cannot figure out how to list all defined indexes within OrientDB. The following is the query syntax if you know the index name:

`SELECT FROM INDEX:<index-name> WHERE key = <key>`

How can I get a list of the existing index-names?

Comment: Have you tried the query from my answer? Let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this query:

```
select expand(indexes) from #0:2
```

or:

```
select expand(indexes) from metadata:indexmanager
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you.